# Using pseudo element to center image at the top of a div

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, pseudo-element

I want to add decoration to the top center of all "well" divs in my bootstrap site using the fluid grid system. This currently seems to work

```
.well {
    position: relative;
}
.well:before {
    content: url("http://placehold.it/20/E8117F");
    top: -10px;
    left: 45%;
    position: absolute;
}
```

But the `left: 45%` is just an approximation to center it, is there a better way to do that?

Here's my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/sguha095/WRB9F/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the content is a fixed width (say 50px) you can set

`left: 50%;` and `margin-left:-25px;` (half the width).

Comment: By "the content" do you mean the image being inserted in the ::before pseudo class?

Answer (score 0):

A little known fact is that CSS treats images as text.  Using that ability, you would want to put a `span` tag around the image and set its style to `text-align: center`, as so:

HTML code:

```
<span class="centerImage"><img src="..." /></span>
```

CSS code:

```
span.centerImage {
     text-align: center;
}
```

The image will be centered.

Comment: I am looking for a solution that doesn't involve adding HTML elements. Check out the jsfiddle in the question http://jsfiddle.net/sguha095/WRB9F/.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with jsfiddle, so sorry if it's a stupid question, but why can't you add html elements?  What I'm getting when I click your link is html and css code, both very change-able.  I fail to see a question there...do you need to have an account?

Comment: You can edit code on jsfiddle, it's more that I wanted a solution that wouldn't require me to edit the html on my page for all `well` divs. Using a pseudoelement confines this presentation logic to the stylesheet.